# Combinational Logic Timing

Tags: hardware, signal-processing, vhdl

I am currently trying to implement a data path, which calculates the following, in one clock cycle.

- Takes input A and B and add them.
- Shift the result of addition, one bit to right. (Dividing by 2)
- Subtract the shifted result from another input C.

The behavioral architecture of the entity is simply shown below.

```
signal sum_out : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
signal shift_out : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

process (clock, data_in_a, data_in_b, data_in_c)
begin
    if clock'event and clock = '1' then
        sum_out <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(data_in_a) + unsigned(data_in_b));
        shift_out <= '0' & sum_out(7 downto 1);
        data_out <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(data_in_c) - unsigned(shift_out));
    end if;
end process;
```

When I simulate the above code, I do get the result I expect to get. However, I get the result, after 3 clock cycles, instead 1 as I wish. The simulation wave form is shown below.

[image: Simulation Waveform]

I am not yet familiar with implementing designs with timing concerns. I was wondering, if there are ways to achieve above calculations, in one clock cycle. If there are, how can I implement them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do do this with signals simply register only the last element in the chain (data_out).  This analyzes, I didn't write a test bench to verify simulation.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity signal_single_clock is
    port ( 
        signal clock:       in  std_logic;
        signal data_in_a:   in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        signal data_in_b:   in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        signal data_in_c:   in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        signal data_out:    out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture behave of signal_single_clock is
    signal sum_out : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    signal shift_out : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
begin
    sum_out <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(data_in_a) + unsigned(data_in_b));
    shift_out <= '0' & sum_out(7 downto 1);
single_reg:
    process (clock)
    begin
        if clock'event and clock = '1' then
            data_out <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(data_in_c) - unsigned(shift_out));
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Thank you David. The code you provided also achieved the timing goal with the correct result. Does this mean that the assigning signals outside of the process block happens in serial manner? (Sum_out is evaluated before shift_out. Then, process happens.)?

Comment: shift_out shouldn't have been in the process sensitivity list, I removed it (multitasking, autopilot error). The reason it works as a chain is that a concurrent signal assignment statement is sensitive to signals on the right hand side. In a zero time model the process will be waiting on clock and shift_out will already be ready.  The assignments to sum_out, shift_out and data_out are sequential but not serial, ordered by events.  Synthesizing the design description would be dependent on gate delays adding up to less than one target clock period.

Comment: I had to read many times to understand it, but I think I have it now. Shift_out will wait for the sum_out to be evaluated, because the shift_out assignment has the sum_out on its right hand side. This will make sure sum_out and shift_out will work sequentially. This was a great help. Thank you very much, David!

Comment: Each concurrent statement has an _equivalent_ process statement, and this is how they are simulated as process statements.  In this case the ones for sum_out and shift_out have no sensitivity lists but end with a last sequential statement: `wait on data_in_a,data_in_b;` or `wait on sum_out;`. As you might expect the only other statement is identical to the concurrent signal assignment statements.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a new value to a signal inside a process, this new value will be available only after the process finishes execution. Therefore, anytime you read the signal's value you will be using the original value from when the process started executing.

On the other hand, assignments to varibles take place immediately, and the new value can be used in the subsequent statements if you wish.

So, to solve you problem, simply implement `sum_out`, `shift_out`, and `data_out` using variables, instead of signals. Then simply copy the value of `data_out` to an output port of your entity.

Comment: Thank you, Rick. The code now shows the result in the next clock cycle. If I may, could I ask if there is a way to achieve the same using the signals only, without using variables?

Comment: Yes, in that case Brian's suggestion is exactly what you need, I suggest that you go with that if you want to use signals.

Answer (score 2):

Without using variables:

```
sum <= in_a + in_b;
process (clock)
begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
        data_out <= in_c - ('0' & sum(7 downto 1));
    end if;
end process;
```

All declarations except clock are `unsigned(7 downto 0);` why make it more complicated than that?

The original, pipelined to 3 cycles, will probably work at higher clock rates.

EDIT following comment:

I wanted to demonstrate that VHDL doesn't really have to be *that* verbose.

However there seem to be a lot of people "teaching" VHDL who are focussing on trivial elements and missing the big picture entirely, so I'll say a little bit about that.

VHDL is a strongly typed language, to prevent mistakes that creep in when types are mistaken for each other and (e.g.) you add two large numbers and get a negative result.

It does NOT follow from that, that you need type conversions all over the place.
Indeed, if you need a lot of type conversions, it's a sign that your design is probably wrong, and it's time to rethink that instead of ploughing ahead down the wrong path.

Code - in ANY language - should be as clean and simple as possible.

Otherwise it's hard to read, and there are probably bugs in it.

The big difference between a C-like language and VHDL is this:

In C, using the correct data types you can write `sum = in_a + in_b;`
and it will work. Using the wrong data types you can also write `sum = in_a + in_b;`
and it will compile just fine; what it actually does is another matter! The bugs are hidden : it is up to you to determine the correct types, and if you get it wrong there is very little you can do except keep on testing.

in VHDL, using the right types you can write `sum <= in_a + in_b;`
and using the wrong types, the compiler forces you to write something like `sum <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(in_a) + unsigned(in_b));` which is damn ugly, but will (probably: see note 1) still work correctly.

So to answer the question : how do I decide to use `unsigned` or `std_logic_vector`?

I see that I need three inputs and an output. I *could* just make them `std_logic_vector`but I stop and ask: what do they represent?

Numbers.

Can they be negative? Not according to my reading of the specification (your question).

So, unsigned numbers... (Note 1)

Do I need non-arithmetic operations on them? Yes there's a shift.(Note 2)

So, `numeric_std.unsigned` which is related to  `std_logic_vector` instead of `natural` which is just an integer.

Now you can't avoid type conversions altogether. Coding standards may impose restrictions such as "all top level ports must be `std_logic_vector`" and you must implement the external entity specification you are asked to; intermediate signals for type conversions are sometimes cleaner than the alternatives, e.g. `in_a <= unsigned(data_in_a);`
Or if you are getting instructions, characters and the numbers above from the same memory, for example, you might decide the memory contents must be `std_logic_vector` because it *doesn't* just contain numbers. But pick the correct place to convert type and you will find maybe 90% of the type conversions disappear. Take that as a design guideline.

(Note 1 : but what happens if C < (A+B)/2 ? Should data_out be signed? Even thinking along these lines has surfaced a likely bug that std_logic_vector left hidden...

The right answer depends on unknowns including the purpose of data_out : if it is really supposed to be unsigned, e.g. a memory address, you may want to flag an error instead of making it signed)

(Note 2 : there isn't a synthesis tool left alive that won't translate 
`signal a : natural; ... x <= a/2` into a shift right, so `natural` would also work, unless there were other reasons to choose unsigned. A lot of people seem to still be taught that integers aren't synthesisable, and that's just **wrong**.)

Comment: Dear Brian. I like your suggestion. It is quite compressed. How would you decide you would use unsigned opposed to std_logic_vector? There is probably reasons why they are separately used, but I cannot tell why.